# Nokogiri table parsing

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, nokogiri

My problem is that I can't get to the second row in this table

It only prints out the text from the td's on the first tr.

```html
<table class="admintabletext" width="99%;" cellspacing="2"
    cellpadding="4">
    <tr>
        <td class="admintabletitletext2">Namn</td>
        <td class="admintabletitletext2">Telefon</td>

        <td class="admintabletitletext2">Mobil</td>
        <td class="admintabletitletext2">&nbsp;</td>
    </tr>

    <tr  bgcolor="#eeeeee">
<td valign="top">name<br>address</td>
<td valign="top">mobile</td>
<td valign="top"><strong>number</strong><br>
</td>

<td valign="top"><a href="#" onclick="return copyValues(0);">Kopiera</a></td>
</tr>
</table>
```

My code looks something like this:

```rb
doc = Nokogiri::HTML(open(url), nil, 'UTF-8')
doc.xpath( '//table/tr/td//text()' ).each_with_index do |td, index|
   # DO stuff with td
end
```

Answer (score 1):

There is problem not in your code. Your code works fine for me.

```
doc.xpath( '//table/tr/td//text()' ).each_with_index do |td, index|
    puts "#{index}. #{td.content}"
end

# 0. Namn
# 1. Telefon
# 2. Mobil
# 3.  
# 4. name
# 5. address
# 6. mobile
# 7. number
# 8. Kopiera
```

Comment: Confirmed; the above code works fine for me. @Mattias, if this is not working for you, you need to provide the actual URL you're parsing, or your actual content. Note that, due to your xpath, you aren't selecting the TD, but rather the text therein.